# GoogleMapで灰色のカバーが表示される

Tags: javascript, google-maps

APIキーを取得し以下のコードで地図を表示させると、地図に灰色のカバーがかかってしまいます。

```html
<div class="map-area">
    <div id="mapField"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&key=APIキー"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function mapInit() {
    //サイズ
    document.getElementById("mapField").style.width = "100%";
    document.getElementById("mapField").style.height = "350px";
    //座標
    var centerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng({{$company->lat}},{{$company->lng}});
    var option = {
        //ズーム
        zoom : 13,
        center : centerPosition,
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var googlemap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapField"), option);
    //情報ウインドウ
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: centerPosition,
        map: googlemap
    });
    var infoWindowOption = {
        position : centerPosition,
        content : "{{$company->name}}",
        pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -30)
    };
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infoWindowOption);
    //infoWindow.open(googlemap);
}
mapInit();
</script>
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

今までこういった表示になったことはないのですが、原因、解決方法がわかる方いらっしゃいますでしょうか。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

追記：以下の公式のコードも試しましたが、同じように灰色のカバーが表示されました。
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map?hl=ja#maps_add_map-css

Comment: ブラウザのJavascriptのコンソールに警告やエラー等はなにか表示されていませんか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。コンソールにエラーは表示されていません。

Comment: オープン前のサイトなのでベーシック認証がかかっているとこのような表示になるのでしょうか。解決せずです。